# xamarin.ios UISegmentedControl Selected Segment is appearing behind the segment

Tags: xamarin.ios

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            BuildInterface();

            /// Works if first load is this way, but otherwise wont work.
            //SegEventHandling.AllEvents += (UISegmentedControl,e) =>
            //{
            //    SegEventHandling.Subviews[0].BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            //    SegEventHandling.Subviews[1].BackgroundColor = Constants.TRKDarkGreen;//.ColorWithAlpha(.5f);
            //    SegEventHandling.Subviews[2].BackgroundColor = Constants.TRKGreen;//.ColorWithAlpha(.5f);
            //    SegEventHandling.Subviews[3].BackgroundColor = Constants.TRKYellow;//.ColorWithAlpha(.5f);
            //    SegEventHandling.Subviews[4].BackgroundColor = Constants.TRKRed;//.ColorWithAlpha(.5f);
            //    SegEventHandling.Subviews[5].BackgroundColor = Constants.TRKDarkRed;//.ColorWithAlpha(.5f);
            //    SegEventHandling.SelectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.White;
            //};
        }
```

The selected segment is white. So when selecting a segment the white color should appear over the selected segment. However, it appears behind the selected segment (you can see a flicker of white over the text when clicking)

If I put the SegEventHandling code into the view did load on its own, that is the behavior you get.

If I put the SegEventHandling code into the event handler I pasted above, it works fine (obviously the colors don't get set until one is clicked -- so it doesn't work the way it is intended)

However, in both situations the UIColor.Clear works fine (you can see the white selected segment color as intended)

What gives?

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here.

Comment: I will try to put this together tomorrow. Another point I forgot to mention is that it only started happening in ios 15+. Worked fine in previous ios versions.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trying to understand how ios/xamarin renders the subviews... I found that setting the background color of each segment within ViewDidAppear fixes the problem. Apparently there is some "magic" behind the scenes that doesn't finish until ViewDidAppear runs (although it did finish when using the event handler like posted).

Anyway, anyone else trying to make each segment a different color, set the colors in ViewDidAppear. (ViewWillAppear and ViewDidLoad wont work)